# calling public function from another php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on WordPress plugin where I have 2 php files.

`class.php` has code as:

```
class Plugin_Name {

     public function say_hello() {
         echo "Hello";
     }

}
```

Now I want to call this `say_hello()` function from another `welcome.php` file.

I tried

```
$hello_function = new Plugin_Name();
$hello_function->say_hello();
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to call public function from another php ?

Comment: did you include `class.php` in `welcome.php` ?

Comment: Is it a typo, or have you not used `;` after the commands? Maybe you're just missing that bit.

Comment: Did you include `class.php` in `welcome.php` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "But it doesn't work."? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the first function in the other file, that way the other file knows the code is there. At the top of welcome.php add

```
require_once('/path/to/class.php');
$hello_function = new Plugin_Name();
$hello_function->say_hello();
```